# Calculate visible area in protovis when using zoom

Tags: javascript, visualization, protovis

Is there someway to get the visible area of the panel when zooming. I 
have a force directed graph and I am interested in obtaining all the 
elements that are in the visible area after a zoom event. 
Any suggestions? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can access the current transformation matrix of a panel via the `transform` parameter. So, in the following example:

```
var vis = new pv.Panel()
    .width(200)
    .height(200);

var panel = vis.add(pv.Panel)
    .event("mousewheel", pv.Behavior.zoom(1))
    .fillStyle('#ccc');

var dot = panel.add(pv.Dot)
    .data([[25,25],[25,75],[75,25],[75,75]])
    .top(function(d) d[0])
    .left(function(d) d[1])
    .size(30)
    .fillStyle('#999');

vis.render();
```

If you load this example, then zoom around a bit, you can access the current transformation matrix like this:

```
var t = panel.transform(),
    tk = t.k, // scale factor, applied before x/y
    tx = t.x, // x-offset
    ty = t.y; // y-offset
```

You should be able to determine whether a child mark (e.g., in this example, `dot`) is in the visible area by applying the transformation matrix to its `top` and `left` parameters and then checking to see whether they're within the panel's original bounding box (0,0,200,200). For the `dot` above, you could check like this:

```
function(d) {
    var t = panel.transform(),
        // assuming the current dot instance is accessible as "this"
        x = (this.left() + t.x) * t.k, // apply transform to dot x position
        y = (this.top() + t.y) * t.k;  // apply transform to dot y position
    // check bounding box. Note that this is a little simplistic - 
    // I'm just checking dot center, not edges
    return x > panel.left() && x < (panel.left() + panel.width()) &&
           y > panel.top() && y < (panel.top() + panel.height());
}
```